# How can I define classes named like SOMETHING.something?

Tags: javascript

I often see classes named like `SOMETHING.something` - such as in Three.js where one can do

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

but I can't figure how to define a class to do that.

I know I can do this:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
}


Foo.Bar = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Foo.Bar.prototype.greet = function(){
    console.log(this.name);
} 

var f = new Foo.Bar('gigi');

f.greet()
```

but it looks like I cannot do this

```
class Foo {
    constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
}

class Foo.Bar {
    constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
}
```

as I get this:

```
class Foo.Bar {
         ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

How can that be done?

Comment: what should be the purpose of the dot in your application?

Comment: If it throws a syntax error, what do you think?

Comment: @ScottMarcus if something throws an error does not mean it's impossible, but probably one does not know syntax, eg: `{foo.bar: 'baz'}` vs `{"foo.bar": 'baz'}`. The former throws an error, but it is possible to use dot as a property name.

Comment: @zerkms The question is not asking about a property name, the question is asking about a class name (*"Can I use a dot in the name of a class?"*) and the dot throws an error with that syntax, so yes, that is impossible.

Comment: @ScottMarcus well, it throws an error in that particular case. There is always a chance you don't know about right syntax, eg imagine there is a syntax like `class $Foo.Bar$` and you're simply unaware of it.

Comment: @zerkms We don't have to imagine additional possible syntax when the interpreter's job is to tell us that `.` is an unexpected identifier in a class name. The message literally means, you can't put a `.` in a class name. How much more information do we need?

Comment: @ScottMarkus I edited the question, I hope it makes it clearer. I was coming from languages where you can say "package Foo::Bar". I understand that's different, and it's cklearer now that "class" acts in the same way as "function"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the new Class to the `Bar` property of `Foo`:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

Foo.Bar = class Bar {
  constructor(name) {
    console.log('making a bar');
    this.name = name;
  }
}

const bar = new Foo.Bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are class expressions:

```
 Foo.Bar = class { /*...*/ };
```

> Can I use a dot in the name of a class?

No. The dot is used in JS to annotate property access, so `Foo.Bar` will always mean "the Bar property of Foo".

Comment: You mean, the Bar property of Foo?